# Getting a 404 error for the Salesforce CDP Consent AP Action "Shouldforget"

Tags: api, error, postman, salesforce-cdp

I am using [Salesforce's documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_consent_cdp_params.htm) on how to use their Consent API to delete records in CDP by using the write parameter action "shouldforget". Nonetheless, I am getting a 404 Not Found error which isn't indicative, especially since I have followed the documentation step by step.

1. Firstly, I received the authentication token which I then exchanged for a CDP authentication token (I have done this process several times and for other API calls - e.g. streaming, bulk, query - it has worked so I am confident the authentication is not the problem).
2. Second, I used the CDP access_token to authenticate my Consent API method via bearer authentication.
   [image]
3. I then entered the following URI with HTTP method "PATCH":
   [image]
4. And after hitting send, I get a 404 error with the only additional details as below:
   [image]
   [image]

Can someone spot what I'm missing/doing wrong or has someone used Consent API with Salesforce API and knows some common errors? I have experienced Salesforce documentation to be erroneous in the past so it's not reliable to make a successful API call.

Thanks in advance! Happy to provide further details if needed.

Answer (score -1):

It is a GET method. not a PATCH.

[image: Documentation]

[source:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_consent_cdp_params.htm)